# Prove a graph with degree $\ge \frac{n}{2}$ has diameter $\leq 2$

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

> $G$ is an undirected connected graph that has an even number of nodes,
>   and every node has $≥ n/2$ degree. Prove that it has diameter $≤ 2$.

I understand that if two vertices are not connected, then each of them has at least $n/2$ edges connecting to the remaining vertices, so they must have a shared neighbor which would make the diameter $2$.

However, I don't know how to prove it formally through direct proof or contradiction, etc. since I am very new to graph theory and not familiar with all the principles and theorems.

Comment: what have you tried? did you draw some examples?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine the diameter of a graph of order $n \geq 3$ where $\delta (G) \geq \frac{n-1}{2}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1980006/determine-the-diameter-of-a-graph-of-order-n-geq-3-where-delta-g-geq-fr)

Comment: @TheHolyJoker I drew some small examples with 2, 4, 6 nodes and noticed that even if there are two unconnected vertices they would still be connected by a neighbor. It makes sense intuitively, but it is hard to write a proof for because it would seem like there's not much to explain.Sorry I am like a complete amateur at proof.

Comment: This is the formal argument for what you just said (pigeonhole principle)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle], which is the proof.

Comment: @TheHolyJoker Oh okay I see. I'll look into the source and incorporate that into my writing. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If the minimal degree, denoted by $\delta(G)$, is equal to $n/2$, and the graph is connected, then every two vertices have a common neighbor (By the pigeonhole principle).

Answer (score 3):

Let $u$ and $v$ be two distinct vertices. Then as $|\{u\}+N_G(u)| \ge \frac{n}{2}+1$ [why is that so] and $|N_G(v)| \ge \frac{n}{2}+1$ it follows that the two sets $\{u\}+N_G(u)$ and $\{v\}+N_G(v)$ intersect [make sure you see why]. As $u$ and $v$ are distinct this implies that either (i) $u \in N_G(v)$ or (ii) $v \in N_G(u)$ or (iii) $N_G(v)$ and $N_G(u)$ intersect [make sure you see why].

If either (i) or (ii) is true then the distance in $G$ between $u$ and $v$ is 1; if (iii) is true then the distance in $G$ between $u$ and $v$ is at most 2.

Thus the distance between any two distinct vertices is 2, which gives the desired result.